# How to click next button while signing in yahoo mail?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to sign in to yahoo mail. Unable to proceed to click the "Next" button. I am not able to find out, where I am missing. Please guide me. Thank you.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class FirstScript {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\selenium-java-            3.141.59\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");                                                                             driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("test@yahoo.com"); //name locator for text box
        WebElement searchIcon = driver.findElement(By.name("signin"));//name locator for next button
        searchIcon.click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("testing"); //name locator for text box
        WebElement searchIcon2 =     driver.findElement(By.name("verifyPassword"));//name locator for next button
        searchIcon2.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a character sequence first to the **Email address** field, invoke `click()` on the button with text as **Next**, send a character sequence to the **Password** field and again invoke `click()` on the button with text as **Next**, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following Locator Strategies:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class A_ChromeTest 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.navigate().to("https://login.yahoo.com/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.phone-no#login-username"))).sendKeys("dev_pspl");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#login-signin")).submit();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#password-container>input"))).sendKeys("test123");
          ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='login-signin']")));
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: yahoo_login]

Comment: Getting an error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 JavascriptExecutor cannot be resolved to a type
 JavascriptExecutor cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Ravi Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is correct. You just have to wait until the screen redirects to the next page. The modified script  (included explicit wait) is below;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class sample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<driverlocation>");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("test@yahoo.com"); // name locator for text box
        WebElement searchIcon = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-signin\"]")));// name locator for next button
        searchIcon.click();
        WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("password")));
        password.sendKeys("testing"); // name locator for text box
        WebElement searchIcon2 = driver.findElement(By.name("verifyPassword"));// name locator for next button
        searchIcon2.click();
    }
}`
```

Comment: Still not able to proceed after the username. It got stuck at the username.

Comment: Can you provide with the exception fired when it get stuck. Seems to be working fine for me....

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.name: password (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
 at edureka.FirstScript.main(FirstScript.java:28)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='password']"}

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and it all worked so worth trying it

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-username")).sendKeys("Test123456789");    
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-signin")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-passwd")).sendKeys("123456");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-signin")).click();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#login-passwd"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

Comment: read more about wait [here](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html). If exact same script works for me but not for you that means when selenium clicks the `#login-passwd`, it is not there. So, you may need to try explicit wait as explained in the article